# Deploying my PyQt5 app to Android

Tags: android, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have written an PyQt5 app with Python 3.6 on Windows, the app is working perfectly on Windows, I used PyInstaller to make one .exe file to run the app, which works great!

Is it possible to make my app work on Android?
I tried PyQtDeployment with no success.

any suggestions?